# Can't get bxslider to reload properly after removing or adding an image to the collection

Tags: angularjs, bxslider

I've run into a bit of an issue (duh.. otherwise i wouldn't be here). I've googled to the best of my powers and can't figure out why it isn't working. I've tried a bunch of things already so buckle up and prepare for a lot of code blocks.

How it looks at the moment:

[image: How it looks at the moment:]

This is the code for my bxslider:

```
<ul class="bx-slider" bx-slider>
    <li class="slide frame fluid image" ng-repeat="img in sliderImages track by $index" notify-when-repeat-finished width="400px" height="225px">
         <a id="reload-slider" class="huge red corner label" ng-click="deleteItem($index)">
             <i class="remove icon"></i>
         </a>
         <img class="image centered" ng-src="../{{img}}"/>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

As you can probably guess, I've turned the jquery plugin into a directive and have also made a directive to broadcast when the ng-repeat is finished:

**BxSlider directive:**

```
module.directive('bxSlider', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //console.log(element);
        scope.$on('repeatFinished', function () {
            console.log("ngRepeat has finished");
            element.bxSlider().bxSlider(scope.$eval('{' + attrs.bxSlider + '}'));
        });
        scope.$on('reload-slider', function() {
            console.log("TEXTS!");
            element.reloadSlider();
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

**Ng-Repeat finished directive:**

```
module.directive('notifyWhenRepeatFinished', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$emit('repeatFinished');
            });
        }
    }
}
}]);
```

When you click on the cross in the top right corner, the image is deleted via this function:

**delete image function**

```
 $scope.deleteItem = function(index){
    alert('deleting item: ' + $scope.sliderImages[index]);
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/guta/API/slides/'+ index}).then(function(result) {
        console.log("Okay.. I finished the post.");
        console.log("Slider images old:", $scope.sliderImages);

        $scope.sliderImages.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("Slider images new:", $scope.sliderImages);
        $scope.$broadcast('reload-slider');
    });
};
```

As you can see, I tried to broadcast reload-slider to the directive and get the element to reload itself. As far as i know, the broadcast should trigger the

```
scope.$on('reload-slider', function(){...}
```

**The Problem:**

The console.log works, but it doesn't reload the slider at all, the images array isn't re-looped, nothing. the only thing it does is log "TEXTS" and throw the file away on the server (as it should)

it should not show the image after it's been deleted

Any help, fixes or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Is the image physically removed from markup after `$scope.sliderImages.splice(index, 1);`? I mean at the moment of `element.reloadSlider();` - how many images are there in the markup?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin thanks for taking the time to comment, but a coworker helped me fix the issue already, we made a filter instead of the scope.$on,  because scope.$on will only fire ONCE for each web-page. we changed some other things as well, so it's difficult to post an answer with the solution. but i'm gonna try anyway to help people out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a coworker helped me fix the problem, here is the working bit.

**The BoxSlider itself:**

```
<ul class="bx-slider" bx-slider="mode: 'horizontal', controls:false">
    <li class="slide frame fluid image" ng-repeat="img in sliderImages|ngRepeatFinish) track by $index" width="400px" height="225px">
        <a id="reload-slider" class="huge red corner label" ng-click="deleteItem($index)">
            <i class="remove icon"></i>
        </a>
        <img class="image centered" ng-src="../{{img}}"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**The Directive:**

```
module.directive('bxSlider', ['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var slider = element;
        $rootScope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function() {
            console.log("repeat finished!!");
            console.log(element);
            if(element.reloadSlider){
                element.reloadSlider();
            }
            else{
                element.bxSlider().bxSlider(scope.$eval('{' + attrs.bxSlider + '}'));
            }

        });
    }
}
}]);
```

**This filter will call out when the ng-repeat is finished**

```
module.filter('ngRepeatFinish', function($timeout, $rootScope){
return function(data){
    var me = this;
    var flagProperty = '__finishedRendering__';
    if(!data[flagProperty]){
        Object.defineProperty(
            data,
            flagProperty,
            {enumerable:false, configurable:true, writable: false, value:{}});
        $timeout(function(){
            delete data[flagProperty];
            $rootScope.$broadcast('ngRepeatFinished');
        },0,false);
    }
    return data;
};
});
```

**The function that is called in the controller when you click the cross:**

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(index){
    alert('deleting item: ' + $scope.sliderImages[index]);
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/guta/API/slides/'+ index}).then(function(result) {
        $scope.sliderImages.splice(index, 1);
    });

};
```

So, i'll try and explain in which order the code runs:

1. The bxSlider loads in after the loop finished (this is learned via the Broadcast on the filter)
2. The User clicks on the cross in the corner of the image he/she wants removed
3. The $index that every image is tracked by is sent to the function that will post the image url to the server with the request to delete
4. The image to be deleted is removed from the server while the front-end uses splice() to remove the image (won't need to request it all anew)
5. (i think) because the array for the ng-repeat is changed, it runs again.
6. after the ng-repeat is finished, the filter calls out again.
7. since the function element.reloadSlider is availible (not undefined) it calls element.reloadSlider(); INSTEAD of reinitializing the entire boxslider, which will cause an ugly bxslider.

if you take a closer look at the bx-slider attribute, you see there are two config options passed in (`bx-slider="mode: 'horizontal', controls:false"`) especially Controls:false is important, this prevents every image from having their own set of prev and next buttons, but only allows the bx-slider itself to have those

*I hope this helps people stuck on an angular bx-slider themselves.*